# Am I modelling my warehouse tables the right way?

Tags: database, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I'm designing a website where users answer surveys. I need to design a data warehouse to aggregate their responses. So far in my model I have:

1. A dim table for Users.
2. A dim table for Questions.
3. A fact table for UserResponses. <= This is where I'm having the problem.

So the problem I have is that additional comments can be added to their responses. For example, somebody may come in and make 2 comments against a single response. How should I model this in the database?

I was thinking of creating another fact table for "Comments", and linking it to a record in UserResponses. Is this the right thing to do? This additional table would have something like the below columns:

1. CommentText
2. Foreign key relationship to fact.UserResponses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your idea to create another table is correct. I would typically call it a "child" table rather than calling it another fact table.

The key thing that you didn't mention is that the table `comments` still needs an ID field. A table without an ID would be bad design (although it is indeed *possible* to create the table with no ID) since you would have no simple way to refer to individual comments.

Comment: Yes very true that's my bad I left it off the question. Will definitely include an id column for it.

Comment: Associating the comments directly to the fact may not be what you want as it will alter the grain of the fact table from User/Response to User/Response/Comment. Given that a data warehouse is normally used for supporting analytically queries, what is the analytical value of these comments and why are you bringing them into your star schema?

Answer (score 0):

In a dimension model, fact tables are never linked to each other, as the grain of the data will be compromised.

The back-end database of a client application is not usually a data warehouse schema, but more of an online transactional processing (OLTP) schema. This is because transactional systems work better with [third normal form](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/third-normal-form-3nf.php). Analytical systems work better with dimensional models because the data can be aggregated (i.e., "sliced and diced") more easily.

I would recommend switching back to an OLTP database. It can still be aggregated when needed, but maintains third normal form for easier transactional processing.

Here is a good comparison between a dimensional model (OLAP) and a transactional system (OLTP):

https://www.guru99.com/oltp-vs-olap.html